# Furnace breaker wont stay on

Tags: circuit-breaker, furnace

I tried turning on the AC and it won’t run.  Checked the breaker box and the furnace breaker is flipped.  The breaker won’t stay in the on position When I flip it bacm.  So I must have a short somewhere.  What can I do to diagnose the furnace?  Thanks

Comment: What type of furnace?  Electric?  Gas? Oil?

Comment: Does the circuit breaker have a TEST button on it?

Comment: Make sure you're trying to reset it correctly. Push it all the way to the off position then to the on position.

Comment: What make and model is your furnace? Is it on its own circuit, or are there other things on the circuit as well?

Comment: This was out of my wheelhouse.  We ended up calling an HVAC guy and it was as simple as replacing the breaker.  Thanks to all of those that replied.